# hover effect reduce web-site speed?

Tags: css, performance, hover, pagespeed, jquery-hover

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neiqi.png)

**How much this code reduce page speed ?
Hover effects in generally a lot reduce speed or nothing reduce ?**

Comment: There is no answer to that. On a normal desktop pc it wouldn't make much of a difference; on an old/embedded machine without discrete graphics it may be noticable. just try it out ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Please don't post code in an image format on this site.  Code should be copied / pasted into the post using the code-block feature available to you when you create your post _ Please visit this link and scroll down to read the 'answer' element of the post to find out more details >>> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question